# JSF:ajax keyup for 2 fields

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, keyup

i have 2 autofill fileds empname and empno if i give empno remaining fields should be autofilled from database,same to empname.but the problem is When i insert new empno remaining entered fields has been set to null,same to empname how to solve it.

```
<h:outputText  value="Employee_no"/>
        <h:inputText id="empp"    value="#{Bean.dto.empno}" >
           <p:ajax event="keyup"  update="empn,des,dep,loc"  listener="#{Bean.Workerno}"/>  
       </h:inputText>
       <h:outputText value="Employee_Name"/>
       <h:inputText id="empn"  value="#{Bean.dto.empname}" >
         <p:ajax event="keyup" update="empp,des,loc,dep"  listener="#{Bean.WorkerName}"/>  
       </h:inputText>
       <h:outputText value="Department"/>
       <h:inputText id="dep"    value="#{Bean.dto.de}" />
       <h:outputText value="Designation"/>
       <h:inputText   id="des"   value="#{Bean.dto.de}" />

        <h:outputText  value="Employee_no"/>
        <h:inputText id="empp"    value="#{Bean.dto.empno}" >
           <p:ajax event="keyup"  update="empn,des,dep,loc"  listener="#{Bean.Workerno}"/>  
       </h:inputText>
       <h:outputText value="Employee_Name"/>
        <h:inputText id="empn"  value="#{Bean.dto.empname}" >
         <p:ajax event="keyup" update="empp,des,loc,dep"  listener="#{Bean.WorkerName}"/>  
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="D"/>
        <h:inputText id="dep"    value="#{Bean.dto.d}" />
         <h:outputText value="Designation"/>
        <h:inputText   id="des"   value="#{Bean.dto.de}" />
```

BEAN

Comment: Until you post your code..no one can't tell that what the problem you have, post your code

Comment: what is the scope of the bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine...

One thing is change the `ajax` event from `KeyUp` to `blur`.

**KeyUp** - Forces to call the listener method for every typing letter.

**Blur**  - Forces to call the listener method when you left the text box after typing the content.

Here you need 'blur' event because you need to call the DB after entered the all `empno` .
Make sure that the values are retrieved from DB, after changed the event

---

As for as my consern your DB value is not getting at  `workerNo()` when ajax listener forces.

**JSF Code**

```
<h:ouputText value="empno"/>
 <p:inputText id="empno" value="#{bean.empno}">
     <p:ajax  event="blur" listener="#{bean.ajaxEvent}" update="empname"/>
 </p:inputText>

 <h:ouputText value="empname"/>
 <p:inputText id="empname" value="#{bean.empname}">
```

**Bean Code**

```
//Setters and getters of empname,empno

 public void ajaxEvent()
 {
   if(getEmpNo()==//DB empno)
   {
      setEmpName("DB empname"); //Here only your updating the name field
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but it returns  same result when i move to next  remaining fields set to be null because i have 2 textfields empno and empname